# Allow user to copy image from picturebox and save it everywhere

Tags: c#, image, clipboard, copy-paste

In my application I have a `pictureBox` that shows an image. When user right clicks on the `pictureBox` and selects `Copy` from the context menu, I want to copy the image into the clipboard so the user can paste it in folders and anywhere else. How can I do that?

EDIT: I use this code but by this user only can paste image into word.

```
var img = Image.FromFile(pnlContent_Picture_PictureBox.ImageLocation);
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ? add some code , let us see what you've already done and help you through the rest

Comment: i use this code but by this user only can paste image into word. `var img = Image.FromFile(pnlContent_Picture_PictureBox.ImageLocation);
            Clipboard.SetImage(img);`

Comment: Is the picture box contain an image from a file, an image from memory or is it rendered upon with the `Paint()` event?

Comment: It is not just Word that accepts images from the clipboard.

Comment: @ja72 he wants to be a able to copy past the files not the content of them. also it seems he is loading the image using a file location (`ImageLocation`).

Comment: I load image in picture box from a file, not memory or use `Paint()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Clipboard.SetImage` copies the image content (binary data) to the clipboard not the file path. To paste a file in Windows Explorer you need to have file paths collection in the clipboard not their content.

You can simply add the path of that image file to a `StringCollection` and then call the `SetFileDropList` method of `Clipboard` to achieve what you want.

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection FileCollection = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
FileCollection.Add(pnlContent_Picture_PictureBox.ImageLocation);
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(FileCollection);
```

Now user can past the file anywhere e.g. Windows Explorer.

More info on `Clipboard.SetFileDropList Method` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setfiledroplist.aspx

Comment: totally works , but what's wrong with this method : `Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox1.Image);`

Comment: `Clipboard.SetImage` copies the image content (binary data) to the clipboard not the file path. to past a file in window explore you need to have file paths in the clipboard not their content.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution when the picture box does not display a file image, but it is rendered upon with GDI+.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // call render function
        RenderGraphics(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // refresh drawing on resize
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void copyToClipboardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create a memory image with the size taken from the picturebox dimensions
        RectangleF client=new RectangleF(
            0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Image img=new Bitmap((int)client.Width, (int)client.Height);
        // create a graphics target from image and draw on the image
        Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(img);
        RenderGraphics(g, client);
        // copy image to clipboard.
        Clipboard.SetImage(img);
    }

    private void RenderGraphics(Graphics g, RectangleF client)
    {
        g.SmoothingMode=SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        // draw code goes here
    }
}
```