# C# Picturebox Image is null when I draw a shape in Paint event

Tags: c#, clipboard, picturebox

I drew a shape in Paint event of a Picturebox.

```
  private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 1, 1, 10, 10);
  }
```

And I tried to copy the image in Picture to Clipboard, but it failed because the pictureBox1.Image was null.

```
  private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Clipboard.SetImage(pictureBox1.Image);
  }
```

The shape is drawn on screen but its Image property is empty.

How can I copy the content in a picturebox to Clipboard?

Comment: Hope [copy image from picturebox and save](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16546952/3796048) helps you

Comment: The basic misunderstanding you have is that the `Paint` event affects only what is shown on the screen; it doesn't do anything to the `PictureBox.Image` property, or any image referenced by that property. The marked duplicate shows how to do this correct. See also [Get bitmap from PictureBox - new instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22969196) and [How can I capture as bitmap only what a picturebox is displaying, without using “copy from screen”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25086374). The latter shows how you could save the image to a file without changing your code above.

Comment: Thanks Peter and Mohit. I solve it with Mohit's answer. Because of the simple words 'Drawing on PictureBox' I could not find the appropriate question and its answer. Anyhow, thanks for indicating my misunderstanding about the Paint event. It is the key knowledge what I should have.